# Is $x+x^{2^t}$ a cube in the finite fields with characteristic 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $m,t$ be two odd positive integers with $m>3$. Let $x\in \mathbb{F}_{2^{2m}}$.  I conjecture that the following assertion holds due to some numerical experiments. However, I only can prove this for the case of $t=1$.

> If $x^{2^m+1}=1$ or $x^{2^m+1}=x+x^{2^m}$, then
> $x+x^{2^t}$ is a cube in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2m}}$.

Here, an element $c$ is called a cube in  $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2m}}$, if $c=a^3$ for some $a \in  \mathbb{F}_{2^{2m}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k = \mathbf{F}_{2^m}$ be the finite field of order $q = 2^m$. Let $l = \mathbf{F}_{2^n}$ be the finite field of order $q^2$.

Since $m$ is an odd, it follows that $q \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, and $q^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$. In particular, $|k^{\times}| = q-1$ has order prime to $3$, and $|l^{\times}| = q^2 - 1$ has order divisible by $3$. Since the non-zero elements of finite fields form a cyclic group, it follows that any element of $k^{\times}$ thought of as an element of $l^{\times}$ will always be a cube.

The Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(l/k)$ of order $2$ is generated by the Frobenius map $\sigma = \mathrm{Frob}_{q}$ such that

$$\sigma(z) = z^q$$

for all $z \in l$.

Let me prove the claim in the case that $N=1$ and $t$ is odd.

Suppose that $N = x^{q+1} = 1$. The same equation holds for all the conjugates of $x$ under $\mathrm{Gal}(l/\mathbf{F}_2)$, and hence it also holds for $y$ where $y^2 = x$ (so $\mathrm{Frob}_2 y = x$). We deduce that $\sigma(x) = x^q = x^{-1}$ and also $\sigma(y) = y^q = y^{-1}$.

Now consider the element

$$z = x + x^{2^t} = y^2 + y^{2^{t+1}} = y^{2^t + 1} (y^{1-2^t} + y^{2^t - 1}).$$

If $t$ is odd, then $2^t + 1$ is divisible by $3$, and thus $y^{2^t+1}$ is a cube. Hence to show that $z$ is a cube it suffices to show that

$$y^{1-2^t} + y^{2^t - 1}$$

is a cube. But it is invariant under $\sigma$, so it lies in $k$, and hence it is a cube from the discussion above.

---

On the other hand, the result doesn't appear to be true in general when $N = 1$ and $t$ is even. Suppose that $m=5$, so $q=32$. Suppose that $x$ is a root of

$$x^{10} + x^9 + x^5 + x + 1 = 0,$$

which is irreducible over $\mathbf{F}_2$, then $x^33 = 1$. On the other hand,

$$(x+x^4)^{341} = x^9 + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + 1,$$

where the latter is a cube root of unity. So $(x+x^4)$ is not a cube in this case. In fact, it has order $1023$ and is a generator of $l^{\times}$.

Comment: @ZhengLijing Since the actual question was wrong, I didn't even think about it, but I am sure something very similar will work (for the cases when it was true).